# How to assign output of compare command to a variable

Tags: bash, compare, sh

i have a problem with compare command.

I use this to output result to screen, but I receive nothing ( echo is empty ) but after executing command I obtain a numeric value

```
COMP=`compare -metric PSNR 00000003.jpg 00000004.jpg difference.png`<br>
echo "$COMP"
```

I tried this:

```
OUTPUT="$(compare -metric PSNR 00000003.jpg 00000004.jpg difference.png)"
echo "${OUTPUT}"
```

But it doesn't help

Comment: Please try to search the web before asking a question.

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried this solution but it doesn't help

Comment: @shellter Thank you for your reply, but the problem was that compare outupt to `stderr` , not to `stdout` as Mark Setchell already told.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compare` writes on `stderr` not `stdout`, so use the following to divert `stderr` to `stdout`:

```
comp=$(compare -metric PSNR 1.png 2.png diff.png 2>&1)
echo $comp
```

Comment: Than you so much! And for the future, how can i understand to where command is writing stderr or stdout ?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. One way to test is to try it like this `command 1> 1.txt 2> 2.txt` and then look in file `1.txt` and see what went to `stdout` and look in `2.txt` and see what went to `stderr`.

Comment: many thanks for your help!